# How to create 2 Flutter (Windows Desktop) windows with separate engines and communicate between them?

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, multiple-monitors

I want to add a feature to our Windows Flutter application. If run with a 2nd external display connected, it will run 2 windows simultaneously. On the main display it will show the application full-screen and on the external display it will show a preview of what is being controlled on the primary window, also full-screen (similar to a Powerpoint Presentation with Presenter View on 2 monitors).

I found these two links which describe that this is certainly possible using `windows/runner/main.cpp` and `windows/runner/run_loop.cpp` in the project:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66876
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53372

However, when adding the "Steps to Reproduce" in cjng96's issue to my project, it runs successfully but only 1 window appears...

Furthermore, I am unsure about how to:

- Specify a different Widget to be shown on the secondary display, and
- How to create a communication between the two views

Alternatively, is this the best approach to achieve this dual-screen goal? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

A proper implementation for multiple windows in flutter seems to be coming soon, as you can see in this video:

[Preview: Multiple windows on desktop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtB-teu57vw)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this got out already or not, but the way I achieved this is by using the extended desktop feature of windows. I then virtually resize two main widgets for each screen, I use four constants to define `WIDTH_FIRST_SCREEN` `HEIGHT_FIRST_SCREEN`, `WIDTH_SECOND_SCREEN`, `HEIGHT_SECOND_SCREEN`, and then build my entire UI based on this.